# PHP: Good ways to Refactor an overwriting method with different return type

Tags: php, return, refactoring, overriding

The return type of a method in a base class has changed. What is a good way to refactor the child method to keep its current return type?

In the following example there is the *Database* class, which now returns a *date* as a simple *string*. The inheriting class, on the other hand, overrides *getDate* and should still return a *DateTime*.

**Note**: The implementation in the base class cannot be changed.

**Idea**:
Renaming the *getDate* method in the *DoStuff* class.

```php
class Database
{
    public function getDate(): string
    {
        return '01-01-0001';
    }
}

class DoStuff extends Database
{
    public function getDate(): DateTime
    {
        return DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', parent::getDate());
    }
}
```

Are there best practices to solve such a problem? Many thanks for the help.

Comment: call basemethod and convert the value. But you'll have to change the name since, it wont be an override anymore.

Comment: you might as well consider [hiding](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-hiding-in-c-sharp/amp/). However im not sure if this concept exists in PHP. Hence the c# link.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, the concept of hiding doesn't seem to be an option in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, the simple way that i see is to create a function that do the conversion, that function would return the DateTime, and you wouldn't need override the getDate:

```
class DoStuff extends Database
{
    public function pickDate(): DateTime
    {
        return DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $this->getTime());
    }
}
```

I hope i've helped